# Information regarding dumbbell use for underweight person

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, health, weight-gain, bodyweight

I'm an underweight person. I can't join gym neither I can buy expensive equipment. These [Dumbbells](https://www.amazon.in/Body-Maxx-Dumbells-Sets-BM-Combo-20/dp/B074L25X26?tag=googinhydr18418-21) seem worth my budget.

But I read at some sites that dumbbells are for making arms strong. So ultimately that will increase weight of arms only?

And if I am wrong, **can I use them to increase my overall weight and gain a normal weight (I don't want to be muscular, just need normal weight)?**

Secondly, for a person with 174 cm height and around 55-58 Kg weight, how much weight of dumbbells is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

You gaining weight is not about the weight of the dumbells, but how much food you eat in the day. If you simply add an extra meal in the day, you will gain weight.

You do want to gain muscles instead of fat of course. So you need to eat more of protein and do body weight exercises such as push ups, squats, pull ups and their subsequent harder progressions. This will spare you the gym and equipment cost.

You need to keep challenging yourself, so you can't stick with one dumbell forever, and would need to keep increasing the weight you lift. Or you can increase intensity with bodyweight exercises.

Comment: So you mean most normal people who are not umderweight and don't do exercise have fat only?

Comment: Also, how is it possible for an underweight guy to just eat enough and get fat? I mean it seems funny for example a bone of say 3cm diameter has afat over it of say 10 cm thickness? I have seen people having a lot of fat but they don't seem funny the way I gave an example. Still you think eating alone will make me fat with very less muscles?

Comment: @vivek Your body has and will gain muscles based on your activity and protein intake. You need to do progressive exercises to gain more muscle - lift weights or do bodyweights. If you don't eat enough, you will be relatively weak. If you eat more than what your body needs, the excess calories gets converted to fat and gets deposited around your body. Some below your skin (subcutaneous), some around your inner organs (visceral).

Comment: I just don't understand this: *You need to do progressive exercises to gain more muscle - lift weights or do bodyweights* Most people I know don't do exercise still have normal weight. I JUST NEED TO ACHIEVE THAT.

Comment: If you only want to gain weight, just eat an extra meal everyday. If you are eating three meals a day, eat lunch a bit earlier and eat something heavy in the evening. That's all you need to do. Those who are "normal weight" either eat more than you or burn less.